# Using series in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have this practice problem to be done in prolog and have no idea how to do it. Could someone help me out?

`series(+N, -Ans)` is true when `Ans` is the Nth number in the series: `3,7,15, 31…`  So `series(1,X)` should give `X = 3` and `series(3,X)` should give `X = 15`.

Comment: Do you see rule of these series?

Answer (score 0):

you can write it just using `nth1`.

```
nth1(1,[3,7,15, 31],Val). % Val will be 3
nth1(3,[3,7,15, 31],Val). % Val will be 15
```